# How can I setup a static IP for router?

Tags: static, routes

Hello stackoverflow community!I have a question.
So let's begin.I have a server at my home and I want to setup a static PUBLIC IP adress for the server... .I have PPPoE/Russia PPPoE wan connection and TP-link router.(model no: TL-WR940N / TL-WR941ND )
Thanks for any answers!

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: I was searching for this reason and I was understand that I need to buy a business services special for that...thx anyway!